# FUSE lib passthrough.c example. Where is it mirrors my / exactly?

Tags: c, linux, filesystems, fuse

I'm new to FUSE and c and FSs and I'm messing with [passthrough FS](https://github.com/libfuse/libfuse/blob/master/example/passthrough.c) example which is given in the libfuse package. Can anyone give a hint where in the code it is commanded that FUSE mirror my root dir, please? Cause I found the two base functions - *xmp_init() and main() - pretty laconic.

Here they are:

```
static void *xmp_init(struct fuse_conn_info *conn,
              struct fuse_config *cfg)
{
    (void) conn;
    cfg->use_ino = 1;
    cfg->entry_timeout = 0;
    cfg->attr_timeout = 0;
    cfg->negative_timeout = 0;

    return NULL;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    umask(0);
    return fuse_main(argc, argv, &xmp_oper, NULL);
}
```

And other functions are just, like, implementations of libfuse interface...stuff. I need to make my own crippled FS, I need to modify passthrough.c so that mounted FS would be a white sheet and I could make use of implemented functions and manage files and stuff.

Answer (score 4):

Try to read implementation of any fuse operation in the example and you will see it. There is no single place where this particular detail about mirroring of a root filesystem is hidden.

For example, let's check [`getattr` fuse operation](https://libfuse.github.io/doxygen/structfuse__operations.html#a60144dbd1a893008d9112e949300eb77), which is similar to [`stat(2)`](https://linux.die.net/man/2/stat) system call, and is expected to return (via pointer) a stat structure of given file.

When some file is accessed in a fuse filesystem, a function implementing gettattr operation is called first, which makes implementation of this operation mandatory.

Looking at [the implementation in the example](https://github.com/libfuse/libfuse/blob/03515bbb3092da9b3c2c6a267de90f9f0dcbdb29/example/passthrough.c#L70):

```
static int xmp_getattr(const char *path, struct stat *stbuf,
           struct fuse_file_info *fi)
{
    (void) fi;
    int res;

    res = lstat(path, stbuf);
    if (res == -1)
        return -errno;

    return 0;
}
```

we see that all this code does is that it just calls `lstat(2)` with the same arguments.

So when you mount this example filesystem like this:

```
$ ./passthrough /tmp/example
```

and then try to list files there:

```
$ ls /tmp/example/
```

fuselib will call `xmp_getattr()` with path `"/"` because you are accessing the root of the fuse filesystem. Then the code in `xmp_getattr()` will just call ordinary syscall for the similar thing so that the root filesystem looks mirrored in `/tmp/example` mountpoint.

Answer (score 1):

marbu's answer is correct. I will only clarify that the path argument passed to `xmp_getattr()` et.al. is relative to the mount point, thus `/tmp/example/` is turned  into `/`. You can compile `passthrough` with the `-g` flag and attach `gdb` on it after you've mounted it to inspect the arguments if you so wish.