# FUSE directory wrapper skeleton

Tags: fuse

FUSE can make virtual directories. Is there a FUSE basic skeleton public implementation ?

For example, fuse will mount directory `a/` and reflect changes to `b/`. When virtual file `a/x.txt` is created, then real file `b/x.txt` is created, etc.

It appears to be useless, but I then could use that as a base code and then do my modifications.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have exactly that as one of the libfuse included examples:
https://github.com/libfuse/libfuse/blob/master/example/passthrough.c

A good practice is as you say to copy the code of an example most relevant for you and expand from there.

See also related question about mirroring a file system: [FUSE lib passthrough.c example. Where is it mirrors my / exactly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47895420/fuse-lib-passthrough-c-example-where-is-it-mirrors-my-exactly)